# CSS Reflection: Can I make it scale & Skew?

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-reflections

Is to possible to have a HTML element with a CSS reflection but also **define the reflection's skew & scale?**

*Note I am only coding for iPad so I'm only using CSS3 -webkit-box-reflection.* Maybe there are -webkit-box-reflection attributes I can define to do this? Such as:

```
style="-webkit-box-reflection: below 0px skew(5) scale(0.5);"
```

PS: Are there ways to get reflections in Firefox, Chrome(webkit should work here shouldn't it?) & IE? As far as I know there you can only use CSS "tricks" to get reflections to work in firefox, is that true? Isn't there a -moz-box-reflection?

Comment: I don't think so: http://davidwalsh.name/css-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that but not in `-webkit-box-reflection`, you should do it with the element too:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(5) scale(0.5);

-webkit-transform:  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
   -moz-transform:  /* FF3.5+  */
    -ms-transform:  /* IE9  */
     -o-transform:  /* Opera 10.5  */
        transform:  /* Standard */
           filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* attr */) /* IE6–IE9 */
             zoom: 1; /* for filter (IE) */
```

but I don't know any cross-browser solution for box-reflect except [canvas](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery)